# PHP - Using Interfaces, Strategy Pattern and Optional Method Parameters

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I was wondering if i could get a bit of help.

I have an interface like so

```
interface BackupContract {
    public function testConn($request, $port);
}
```

Then the 2 example implementations of this interface is as follows

```
class FTPBackup implements BackupContract {
    public function testConn($request, $port = 21) {
        // code here
    }
}

class SFTPBackup implements BackupContract {
    public function testConn($request, $port = 22) {
        // code here
    }
}
```

As i need things like 'service' and port designated at runtime, im using 'strategy pattern' to achieve this, like so.

```
class BackupStrategy {
    private $strategy = NULL;

    public function __construct($service) {

        switch ($service) {
            case "ftp":
                $this->strategy = new FTPBackup();
                break;
            case "sftp":
                $this->strategy = new SFTPBackup();
                break;
        }

    }

    public function testConn($request, $port)
    {
        return $this->strategy->testConn($request, $port);
    }
}
```

and finally, in my controller im using the following code to put it all together.

```
$service = new BackupStrategy($request->input('service'));
$service->testConn($request, $request->input('port'));
```

The problem is, that if a user doesnt enter a port, it is meant to auto assign a port variable, i.e 21 or 22 like in the 2 implementations.

It doesn't seem to be working, but its not throwing any errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are always setting a port in `BackupStrategy->testConn($request, $port)` method. So if somebody doesn't give a port, it will pass an empty string.

I would implement a fallback function.

And what @simon said, you are using the wrong method name in your controller.

Answer (score 5):

But you shouldnt implement the switch in the BackupStrategy's constructor.

With your aproach, you are violating the "open/close" principle from the S.O.L.I.D 's principles.

Any time you need to add another "backup strategy" you need to *modify* the BackupStrategy class, adding the logic to the constructor.
**Thats not good.**

You could make sublcasses, each implementig the implementation (LOL) of each backup strategy classes and only inherating the necessary from BackupStrategy class.

```
interface BackupContract {
    public function testConn($request, $port);
}

class FTPBackup implements BackupContract {
    public function testConn($request, $port = 21) {
        // code here
    }
}

class SFTPBackup implements BackupContract {
    public function testConn($request, $port = 22) {
        // code here
    }
}

class BackupStrategy
{
    private $strategy;

    public function testConn($request, $port)
    {
        return $this->strategy->testConn($request, $port);
    }
}

class ConcreteFTPBackup extends BackupStrategy
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->strategy = new FTPBackup();
    }
}

class ConcreteSFTPBackup extends BackupStrategy
{
    function __construct()
        {
        $this->strategy = new SFTPBackup();
    }
}

$service = new ConcreteFTPBackup();

$serice->testConn($request, $request->input('port'));
```

Or even this:

```
interface BackupContract {
    public function testConn($request, $port);
}

class FTPBackup implements BackupContract {
    public function testConn($request, $port = 21) {
        // code here
    }
}

class SFTPBackup implements BackupContract {
    public function testConn($request, $port = 22) {
        // code here
    }
}

class BackupStrategy
{
    private $strategy;

    function __construct(BackupContract $bc)
    {
        $this->strategy = $bc();
    }

    public function testConn($request, $port)
    {
        return $this->strategy->testConn($request, $port);
    }
}


$service = new BackupStrategy(new FTPBackup());

$serice->testConn($request, $request->input('port'));
```

Then you could implement the switch during runtime.

Also you could make a setStrategy method in BackupStrategy class that set or *change* the backup strategy during runtime:

```
public function setStrategy(BackupContract $bc)
{
    $this->strategy = $bc();

}
```

So now, you can create a service with one backup strategy during runtime, and even change the strategy during runtime also!!
Chekit out:

```
$service = new BackupStrategy(new FTPBackup());
$service->testConn($request, $request->input('port'));


$service->setStrategy(new SFTPBackup());
$service->testConn($request, $request->input('port'));
```

The BackupStrategy class is where all your encapsulated algorithms will converge, but don forget the **"encapsulation"** in all this!

The most important in the Strategy Pattern is the encapsulation of a family of algorithms that can be used during runtime!

Hope it helps you!

Comment: why you use brackets on $bc()?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Simon and Laurent.

You're using interfaces, so the implementation should match.

A possible solution:

```
interface BackupContract {
    public function testConn($request, $port = 0);
}
```

But personally, I don't prefer this approach. Optional things in interfaces means that you should validate in possible each implementation instead of trusting the implementation.

Secondly, I recommend using type declarations (PHP7), for example:

```
public function foo(int $bar) : bool
{
    return true;  
}
```

This method expects an integer as argument (must) and a boolean value as return (must). Using $bar, you are sure that this var type is an integer.

See for more information: http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a `testConnection();` method which doesn't exist. What you actually want to call is `testConn();`

Check your error reporting settings because this should definitely throw an error.

Comment: sorry, i forgot to change that ...it does check testConn()